# get multiple url image from server and show in scrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

can anyone please tell me how to get url image ans show in uiscrollview in tableview. I am struggling from last three days but not output.:(

```
<slider1>
 <item>
 <thumbNail>http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png</thumbNail>
   <contentId>img001</contentId>
   </item>
  <item>
     <thumbNail>http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png</thumbNail>
    <contentId>img002</contentId>
  </item>
  <item>
  <thumbNail>http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png</thumbNail>
    <contentId>img003</contentId>
     </item>
    <item>
    <thumbNail>http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png</thumbNail>
    <contentId>img004</contentId>
     </item>
     <item>
     <thumbNail>http://www.bizfy.com/demo/biscoot/a1.png</thumbNail>
  <contentId>img005</contentId>
   </item>
   </slider1>
```

I want to store all images url and show in uiscrollview in tableview cell. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

where is the complication?

Parse the XML to get all urls. Put these urls in a `NSArray`. Now feed this NSArray as a `datasource` to a `UITableView` instance. Make sure the `UITableViewCell` has a `UIImageView` in it so that you can insert the image urls when scroll happens. Thats it, this is all there is to it.

One more important point, assigning `url` to `uiimageview` in main UI thread will hang the UI as it is downloading the image in the main thread. So you will have to do the image downloading in a spawned background thread and then once the image has been downloaded update the `uimageview` in the main UI thread. This way the user experience would be smooth.

Since you have not posted any code, neither am i...